# player SKPhysicsBody passes through other SKPhysicsBody swift 4 Xcode 9

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, skphysicsbody

I'm creating a simple tap to flap game following the instructions from the book swift 3 game development. 
I have two SKSpriteNodes one is the player and the other is a static object that can hurt the player if it makes contact.

Damage to the player will be implemented through custom contact logic through the categoryBitMask. The problem is when I set the categoryBitMask of the static object then when the player makes contact with the static object the custom logic is triggered but the player now moves through the static object.

Here are the init() functions for both player and static object

static object

```
    init() {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: initialSize)
    createAnimations()
    self.run(spinAnimation)
    let startTexture = textureAtlas.textureNamed("blade")
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: startTexture, size:   initialSize)
    self.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
    self.physicsBody?.isDynamic = false
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.enemy.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = ~PhysicsCategory.heroDamage.rawValue
    self.zPosition = -9
  }
```

player

```
    init() {
    super.init(texture: nil, color: .clear, size: initialSize)
    let textureBody = textureAtlas.textureNamed("pierre-flying-3")
    self.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: textureBody, size: self.size)
    self.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.9
    self.physicsBody?.mass = 30
    self.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    self.zPosition = 1
    createAnimations()
    self.run(soarAnimation, withKey: "soarAnimation")
    self.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.hero.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground.rawValue |
                                           PhysicsCategory.enemy.rawValue |
                                           PhysicsCategory.coin.rawValue |
                                           PhysicsCategory.powerUp.rawValue
    self.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.ground.rawValue
}
```

If I remove the isDynamic = false condition then yes it works but the object is no longer static. I've tried increasing the mass of the object and removing the isDynamic = false also. But for some strange reason this has the same effect of just including the IsDynamic = false statement

any help ? Thanks

edit
The enumeration of the categoryBitMask values

```
enum PhysicsCategory:UInt32 {
case hero = 1
case heroDamage = 2
case ground = 4
case enemy = 8
case coin = 16
case powerUp = 32
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One of the two nodes that should collide **needs** to be **dynamic** in order for a collision to take place. You can't have them all static.

Comment: The hero is set to isDynamic = true by default. I have just tried adding the line to hero init() just in case and the results are the same.

Comment: Can you add the PhysicsCategory-enum to the answer? It might help.