# How to make a Sprite an obstacle for another Sprite?

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a game with sprites that move and obstacles to learn SpriteKit. I want the sprites that move to collide with the obstacles and bounce off of them but I want the obstacles to stay fixed. How do I do this? I have tried the following with no success:

- Setting `obstacle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true`. This made the sprites go through the obstacle.
- Fixing the movement and rotation of the object with [`SKConstraint`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/spritekit/skconstraint). When I do this they just go through each other.
- Setting the mass of the body to be really high as follows `obstacle.physicsBody?.mass = CGPoint.maxFiniteMagnitude` but this freezes the game. When I set it really high it doesn't seem to do anything.
- Setting `obstacle?.physicsBody.velocity = CGVector(dx: 0, dy: 0)` when the objects collide. I know that the `contact.bodyA` and `contact.bodyB` are passed by value and not reference so I loop through an array with the obstacles and set the velocity this way. The obstacles are still pushed by the other sprites.

**Update:**
- Setting `obstacle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.none` so the sprite collides with the obstacle but not the other way around.

The object is setup as follows, with fish being the other sprite:

```
obstacle.position = location
obstacle.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(rectangleOf: obstacle.size)
obstacle.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true
obstacle.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = PhysicsCategory.obstacle
obstacle.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = PhysicsCategory.fish
obstacle.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = PhysicsCategory.fish
obstacle.physicsBody?.usesPreciseCollisionDetection = true
self.obstacles.append(obstacle)
super.addChild(obstacle)
```

Please let me know if there is something I am doing wrong / misunderstanding. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46553452/player-skphysicsbody-passes-through-other-skphysicsbody-swift-4-xcode-9?rq=1). One of the objects needs to have `.physicsBody?.isDynamic = true`. In this case I set the obstacle to `false` so it is stationary.